# Sum a specific column based upon a condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, tidyverse

I have the follow set of data:

[image]
Using R and tidyverse if possible I would like to sum column S based upon a condition on other columns.  If my variable

```
condition_columns = c('A', 'B')
```

The output I am after is a data frame containing

[image: A B 490 250]

Where the 490 is obtained by summing column S only when A=1 and  the 250 comes from summing column S when B=1.

Could anyone suggest a tidyverse way of doing it?
Thank you,
Phil,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `summarize(across())`

```
summarize(df, across(all_of(condition_columns), ~sum(S[.x==1])))
```

Output:

```
    A   B
1 490 250
```

Input:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:10, A = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    B = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), S = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 
    50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following (easy to understand) code :

```
df %>% 
  summarise(A = sum(A*S),
            B = sum(B*S))
```

Output:

```
    A   B
1 490 250
```

Comment: agree, definitely clearer/easier if the columns (in this case `A` and `B`) are few in number and can be hard-coded, rather than in a dynamic variable like `condition_columns`, and if the values of said columns only take values `0` and `1`